# Avoid delay when using `*ngIf` in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have four tabs and the fourth one need to be displayed based on whether an API response is present or not. So I am using the following code.

```
<li *ngIf="notifications.length !=0">
    <a data-toggle="tab">Notifications</a>
</li>
```

So the problem with this is , it has a delay when before displaying the `Notifications` tab, if notifications response is present. The other tabs are rendered first and then after a small delay the notifications tab is rendered. How can I avoid this delay and show all the four tabs at the time of page loading ?

Comment: Disable the fourth one instead of deleting it from the DOM ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a route resolver to access your page with your tabs.

The resolver allows to wait for a promise / observable to complete before allowing the navigation to a specific route.
Using your API response call as the completion of your observable, you will be able to wait for the call to be finished to load your component.

This will cause a delay to display your page though; you might want to implement a loader or something like this on your page while it is resolving the route.

Here is an article with examples about resolvers : https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/

Comment: True, but it gives at delay for the whole page, while the OP asks for no delay. Not sure if it fits his needs, but definitely an answer worthy of an upvote.

Comment: This will work for me. Will accept the answer once tested.

Comment: There is one more thing. I actually call a service with some parameters and the service call is inside a function and it is called in `ngOnInit();` So how can I pass these parameters to the resolver service call ?

Comment: It depends from where those parameters come from. If it is from the route, you can get them the same way you do in your `ngOnInit()` function, if it is from another service you do an injection dependency in your resolver directly.

If you still end-up in a stuck situation with your parameters, it probably means you have an architecture issue with your components and services. You shouldn't have any issue to retrive your parameters in your resolver.